# Why is manual null check required when ? operator is there in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
String playerName(String? name) {
  if (name != null) {
    return name;
  } else {
    return 'Guest';
  }
}
```

`?` checks whether `name` is null or not, then why is special `if (name != null) {` condition required?

Comment: "`?` checks whether `name` is null or not" What makes you think that?

Comment: No, `String? name` makes it possible for `name` variable to be either `null` or `String`, but your `playerName`'s function return type is `String` which can't be null, so you can't return name if it's null, only if it isn't.

Comment: This can be written more succinctly: `String playerName(String? name) => name ?? 'Guest';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String? name` means that the parameter `name` is nullable as you can see lower in the code the if statement then checks if your parameter is not null.

Dart docs definition:

> If you enable null safety, variables can’t contain null unless you say they can. You can make a variable nullable by putting a question mark (?) at the end of its type. For example, a variable of type int? might be an integer, or it might be null. If you know that an expression never evaluates to null but Dart disagrees, you can add ! to assert that it isn’t null (and to throw an exception if it is). An example: int x = nullableButNotNullInt!

[Link to docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts)